# What does 'kinetically accessible' mean in protein folding?

Tags: protein-folding

The [hydrophobic collapse model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobic_collapse) discusses this term in the energetics section. What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 3):

At some point during protein folding, there may exist lower energy states from a thermodynamic perspective (lower ΔG free enegy) which are actually unreachable in a given environment, because the required [activation energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy) is too high. These are kinetically inaccessible states, conversely accessible state are those that can be reached.

For example, that could mean a protein could reach a lower energy state by unfolding a bit, but exposing hydrophobic amino acid even temporarily would require too much energy. So the lower energy state is not kinetically accessible.

This is somewhat similar to the concept of [kinetic and thermodynamic reaction products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_versus_kinetic_reaction_control) in chemistry.